# Why do Trampolines work?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I've been doing some functional JavaScript. I had thought that [Tail-Call Optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Tail_call_optimization) had been implemented, but as it turns out I was wrong. Thus, I've had to teach myself [Trampolining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trampoline_(computing)). After a bit of reading here and elsewhere, I was able to get the basics down and constructed my first trampoline:

```
/*not the fanciest, it's just meant to
reenforce that I know what I'm doing.*/

function loopy(x){
    if (x<10000000){ 
        return function(){
            return loopy(x+1)
        }
    }else{
        return x;
    }
};

function trampoline(foo){
    while(foo && typeof foo === 'function'){
        foo = foo();
    }
    return foo;
/*I've seen trampolines without this,
mine wouldn't return anything unless
I had it though. Just goes to show I
only half know what I'm doing.*/
};

alert(trampoline(loopy(0)));
```

My biggest issue, is I don't know why this works. I get the idea of rerunning the function in a while loop instead of using a recursive loop. Except, technically my base function already has a recursive loop. I'm not running the base `loopy` function, but I am running the function inside of it. What's stopping `foo = foo()` from causing a stack overflow? And isn't `foo = foo()` technically mutating, or am I missing something? Perhaps it's just a necessary evil. Or some syntax I'm missing.

Is there even a way to understand it? Or is it just some hack that somehow works? I've been able to make my way through everything else, but this one has me befuzzled.

Comment: "What's stopping foo = foo() from causing a stack overflow?" Well `foo` (in this case `loopy` doesn't call itself, so it's not a recursive call which would overflow.

Comment: @tkausl True, but something like `foo(x){return bar(x)}` and `bar(x){return foo(x)}` also aren't calling themselves but still overflow the stack.

Comment: Yes, but thats still recursion. `loopy` doesn't overflow because it _doesn't call itself_.

Comment: *"I had thought that TCO had been implemented, but as it turns out I was wrong."* It has been at least in V8 in most scenaros. You can use it for instance in any recent version of Node by telling Node to enable it in V8: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30369729/157247 Chrome's had it (behind an "experimental" flag) since Chrome 51.

Comment: The kinetic energy from the user is transformed to elastic potential energy as the trampoline sags, then back to kinetic energy as it rebounds.

Comment: @immibis, On behalf of everyone who came here without checking which Stack Exchange site this was, thank you.

Comment: @user1717828 I knew which site it was, but I was just hoping! ;-)

Comment: @jpaugh did you mean "hopping"? ;-)

Comment: I know that they're not necessarily duplicates across sites, but you may find some this SO question relevant: [What is a trampoline function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189725/what-is-a-trampoline-function/11921515),

Comment: @Hulk I believe I *did!*

Answer (score 92, accepted):

The reason your brain is rebelling against the function `loopy()` is that it is of an *inconsistent type*:

```
function loopy(x){
    if (x<10000000){ 
        return function(){ // On this line it returns a function...
            // (This is not part of loopy(), this is the function we are returning.)
            return loopy(x+1)
        }
    }else{
        return x; // ...but on this line it returns an integer!
    }
};
```

Quite a lot of languages don't even let you do things like this, or at least demand a lot more typing to explain just how this is supposed to make any kind of sense.  Because it really doesn't.  Functions and integers are totally different kinds of objects.

So let's go through that while loop, carefully:

```
while(foo && typeof foo === 'function'){
    foo = foo();
}
```

Initially, `foo` is equal to `loopy(0)`.  What is `loopy(0)`?  Well, it's less than 10000000, so we get `function(){return loopy(1)}`.  That's a truthy value, and it's a function, so the loop keeps going.

Now we come to `foo = foo()`.  `foo()` is the same as `loopy(1)`.  Since 1 is still less than 10000000, that returns `function(){return loopy(2)}`, which we then assign to `foo`.

`foo` is still a function, so we keep going... until eventually foo is equal to `function(){return loopy(10000000)}`.  That's a function, so we do `foo = foo()` one more time, but this time, when we call `loopy(10000000)`, x is not less than 10000000 so we just get x back.  Since 10000000 is also not a function, this ends the while loop as well.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46687/discussion-on-answer-by-kevin-why-do-trampolines-work).

Comment: It's really just a sum type. Sometimes known as a variant. Dynamic languages support them rather easily because *every* value is tagged, while more statically-typed languages will require you to specify the function returns a variant. Trampolines are easily possible in C++ or Haskell, for example.

Comment: @GManNickG: Yes, that's what I meant by "a lot more typing."  In C you would have to declare a union, declare a struct which tags the union, pack and unpack the struct at either end, pack and unpack the union at either end, and (probably) figure out who owns the memory which the struct inhabits.  C++ is very likely less code than that, but it's not conceptually any less complicated than C, and it's still more verbose than OP's Javascript.

Comment: Sure, I'm not contesting that, I just think the emphasis you put on it being weird or not making sense is a bit strong. :)

Answer (score 176):

Kevin succinctly points out how this particular code snippet works (along with why it's quite incomprehensible), but I wanted to add some information about how trampolines *in general* work.

Without tail-call optimization (TCO), every function call adds a *stack frame* to the current execution stack. Suppose we have a function to print out a countdown of numbers:

```
function countdown(n) {
  if (n === 0) {
    console.log("Blastoff!");
  } else {
    console.log("Launch in " + n);
    countdown(n - 1);
  }
}
```

If we call `countdown(3)`, let's analyze how the call stack would look without TCO.

```
> countdown(3);
// stack: countdown(3)
Launch in 3
// stack: countdown(3), countdown(2)
Launch in 2
// stack: countdown(3), countdown(2), countdown(1)
Launch in 1
// stack: countdown(3), countdown(2), countdown(1), countdown(0)
Blastoff!
// returns, stack: countdown(3), countdown(2), countdown(1)
// returns, stack: countdown(3), countdown(2)
// returns, stack: countdown(3)
// returns, stack is empty
```

With TCO, each recursive call to `countdown` is in *tail position* (there's nothing left to do other than return the result of the call) so no stack frame is allocated. Without TCO, the stack blows up for even slightly large `n`.

Trampolining gets around this restriction by inserting a wrapper around the `countdown` function. Then, `countdown` doesn't perform recursive calls and instead immediately returns a function to call. Here's an example implementation:

```
function trampoline(firstHop) {
  nextHop = firstHop();
  while (nextHop) {
    nextHop = nextHop()
  }
}

function countdown(n) {
  trampoline(() => countdownHop(n));
}

function countdownHop(n) {
  if (n === 0) {
    console.log("Blastoff!");
  } else {
    console.log("Launch in " + n);
    return () => countdownHop(n-1);
  }
}
```

To get a better sense of how this works, let's look at the call stack:

```
> countdown(3);
// stack: countdown(3)
// stack: countdown(3), trampoline
// stack: countdown(3), trampoline, countdownHop(3)
Launch in 3
// return next hop from countdownHop(3)
// stack: countdown(3), trampoline
// trampoline sees hop returned another hop function, calls it
// stack: countdown(3), trampoline, countdownHop(2)
Launch in 2
// stack: countdown(3), trampoline
// stack: countdown(3), trampoline, countdownHop(1)
Launch in 1
// stack: countdown(3), trampoline
// stack: countdown(3), trampoline, countdownHop(0)
Blastoff!
// stack: countdown(3), trampoline
// stack: countdown(3)
// stack is empty
```

At each step the `countdownHop` function *abandons* direct control of what happens next, instead returning a function to call that describes what it would *like* to happen next. The trampoline function then takes this and calls it, then calls whatever function *that* returns, and so on until there is no "next step". This is called trampolining because the flow of control "bounces" between each recursive call and the trampoline implementation, instead of the function directly recurring. By abandoning control over who *makes* the recursive call, the trampoline function can ensure the stack doesn't get too large. Side note: this implementation of `trampoline` omits returning values for simplicity.

It can be tricky to know whether this is a good idea. Performance can suffer due to each step allocating a new closure. Clever optimizations can make this viable, but you never know. Trampolining is mostly useful for getting around hard recursion limits, for instance when a language implementation sets a maximum call stack size.

Answer (score 18):

Maybe it becomes easier to understand if the trampoline is implemented with a dedicated return type (instead of abusing a function):

```
class Result {}
// poor man's case classes
class Recurse extends Result {
    constructor(a) { this.arg = a; }
}
class Return extends Result {
    constructor(v) { this.value = v; }
}

function loopy(x) {
    if (x<10000000)
        return new Recurse(x+1);
    else
        return new Return(x);
}

function trampoline(fn, x) {
    while (true) {
        const res = fn(x);
        if (res instanceof Recurse)
            x = res.arg;
        else if (res instanceof Return)
            return res.value;
    }
}

alert(trampoline(loopy, 0));
```

Contrast this to your version of `trampoline`, where the recursion case is when the function returns another function, and the base case is when it returns something else.

> What's stopping `foo = foo()` from causing a stack overflow?

It does not call itself any more. Instead, it returns a result (in my implementation, literally a `Result`) that conveys whether to continue the recursion or whether to break out.

> And isn't `foo = foo()` technically mutating, or am I missing something? Perhaps it's just a necessary evil.

Yes, this is exactly the necessary evil of the loop. One could write `trampoline` without mutation as well, but it would require recursion again:

```
function trampoline(fn, x) {
    const res = fn(x);
    if (res instanceof Recurse)
        return trampoline(fn, res.arg);
    else if (res instanceof Return)
        return res.value;
}
```

Still, it shows the idea of what the trampoline function does even better.

The point of trampoling is *abstracting out* the tail-recursive call from the function that wants to use recursion into a return value, and doing the actual recursion in only one place - the `trampoline` function, which then can be optimised in a single place to use a loop.

Comment: `foo = foo()` is mutation in the sense of modifying local state, but I'd generally consider that reassignment as you aren't actually modifying the underlying function object, you're replacing it with the function (or value) it returns.

Comment: @JAB Yes, I didn't mean to imply mutating the value that `foo` contains, only the variable is modified. A `while` loop requires some mutable state if you want it to terminate, in this case the variable `foo` or `x`.

Comment: I did something like this a while back in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39350385/1281433) to a Stack Overflow question about tail call optimization, trampolines, etc.

Comment: Your version without mutation has converted a recursive call of `fn` into a recursive call to `trampoline` - I'm not sure that's an improvement.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson It's only meant to demonstrate the abstraction. Of course a recursive trampoline is not useful.

Comment: The recursive trampoline *is* useful if you're working in an environment that supports TCO but your recursive function uses recursion in a non-tail position.  In that case, it simply converts a non-tail call to a tail call.

Comment: @PeriataBreatta You cannot use a trampoline for non-tail-calls afaik? You'd still have to `return new Recurse(…)`. But yeah, I guess one could find it valuable it in an environment that supports tail calls only for self-calling functions, but not for tail calls in general or mutual recursion etc.

Comment: @Bergi - you *can*, but it gets complicated.  You need to return a function that is the calculation performed after the recursive call, as well as details of the call that needs to be made.  The trampline then calls the former with the result of the latter to produce the result.

Comment: @PeriataBreatta So if the recursive call returns another non-tail-recursion, the trampoline keeps a *stack* of after-call-calculations? Now that's just an interpreter, not a trampoline for efficient tail calls.

Comment: @Bergi - if the calculations don't require full closures, it uses a lot less memory than a call stack.  Especially if they are always the same, or come from a predictable set, such that the functions can  be statically allocated and shared between each invocation.